# How to add a height attribute to img tag?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have lots of images, all images' original width is 100px, but original height is different. How can I add height attribute based on the original height of these images automatically. Such as

```
<img src="picture.jpg" width="100" height="132">
<img src="picture.jpg" width="100" height="45">
<img src="picture.jpg" width="100" heighst="321">
<img src="picture.jpg" width="100" height="136">
<img src="picture.jpg" width="100" height="214">
......
```

I try this, I try to get the original height of each images first,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$items = $('img');
$.each($items,function(k, v){
    console.log(v.naturalHeight);
    });
  });
```

it doesn't work

This works sometimes

```
 $items = $('img');
    $.each($items,function(k, v){

        $(this).load(function(){

            console.log($(this)[0].naturalHeight);
            $(this).attr('height', $(this)[0].naturalHeight);

        });
    });
```

The problem is that how can I make sure all the images have been loaded before I run the script?

Comment: Do you mean the image's original size?

Comment: Need more info, you'll put this values based in what? Becouse if you will set the original size of the imagem, you just don't need it. Let it empty and the img will assume the height size from image, but if you want to set other value how you'll set it?

Comment: How do you exactly differ heights among all the images, which one should get how much ?

Comment: Don't set a height and it will automatically use the appropriate height to keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: If you need to set it manually, equation is: `newHeight = (originalHeight/ originalWidth) x newWidth`. Otherwise just set the width as per above comments.

Comment: What height should be applied to each image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest implementation would be to wait for all the images to load, and then setting the attribute using JavaScript (I notice you're using jQuery).

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $.each($('img'), function(){

        // Set the height, hard-style!
        $(this).attr('height', $(this).height());

    });

});
```

Obviously, there are other - arguably better - ways to do this (like setting each image's height as it loads), but this should suffice.

---

Have a look at the [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) jQuery plugin and maybe wrap the above `$.each()` in one of it's methods, e.g.:

```
imagesLoaded( '#yourContainer', function() {

    $.each($('img'), function(){

        $(this).attr('height', $(this).height());

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But it only works on the first img tag, others equal to 0, so weird

Comment: I just rechecked, this really does work, but you _have to_ wait until the images have loaded completely. I've updated my answer to include an explanation on using a plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not attribute a height, the image will keep its original proportion.

Otherwise, you can do it with JavaScript, like this :

```
function loaded() {
    var img = document.getElementById("imgID");
    img.style.height = img.height;
}
```

EDIT :
If you don't have IDs on your images :

```
function loaded() {
    var images = getElementsByTagName(img);

    for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].style.height = img.height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would anyone do this? The only effect it has is that if the images are not yet loaded, the height will be set to zero and the images will never display.

Comment: @Fredrik You're true, I edited my post. We can do it in loaded() function to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Thanks! DO I have to add a 'imgID' for each img tag?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you don't have IDs on your images. You can use `document.getElementsByTagName(img)` and do this to all elements returned.

Comment: I've edited my post with the code to do it without having IDs on your images.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
     $("img.adjust-image").height("100px");
})()
```

`$('img.adjust-image')` returns array of all `<img>`elements that has `class=adjust-image` class attribute. So We can add the `height` property for all the images that goes under it.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to add height attribute at all, only width, and image will scale automatically.

Comment: That is true, however that is not a good answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks! But I do need to add these attributes. How can I do this?